# Regarding direct multiplication of scalar with list

Tags: python, list, numpy, multiplication

The snippet was supposed to store/print instantaneous voltage/current values generated by the sin and the arrange functions in `numpy`. I first had `tolist()` after those functions, but the multiplication of the magnitude (230 in the case of voltage, 5 in the case of current) had no effect on the result unless I removed the `tolist()`. Why does that occur?

```
    V_magnitude = 230
    I_magnitude = 5
    voltage = V_magnitude*np.sin(np.arange(0,10,0.01)).tolist()
    current = I_magnitude*np.sin(np.arange(-0.3,9.7,0.01))
```

What I've tried

-> making both the magnitudes as the second operand for multiplication

-> with and without `tolist()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you multiply a `list` by X you extend the list to contain X times the values in it.

When you multiply `numpy` array by X you multiply the values inside the array by X.

Try it with a simple example

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
print(lst * 3)           # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
print(np.array(lst) * 3) # [3 6 9]
```